# Variable "i" acts oddly, jQuery functions not doing what I want them to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an ascii game.

```
    $("#GameContainer").eq(i).contents().html(map[i]);
```

This line of code. I have no idea why, but it's not working. I've spent the past few hours trying to figure it out, but nope.

```
function startGame() {
    map = map_Default.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        $("#GameContainer").eq(i).contents().html(map[i]);
    }
}
```

So in the `for` loop, when called in the `eg()` function, it acts like it should, being 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and so on. When called in the `html()` function, it seems to stay at 0, so instead of rendering the map like normal it repeats the first row of tiles. Also, I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have to use the `contents()` function, but when I don't the `html()` function just replaces every child of `#GameContainer` with `map[i]`.

Here's more:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mapl_Half = Math.floor(map.length / 2);
    var trl_Half = Math.floor(map[mapl_Half].length / 2);
    var whitespace = Math.floor(trl_Half - (startmessage.length / 2));
    map[mapl_Half] = map[mapl_Half].substring(0, whitespace) + startmessage + map[mapl_Half].substring(whitespace + startmessage.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        $("#GameContainer").append("<p class=\"tilerow\">" + map[i] + "</p>");
    }
    $(document).keydown(function (key) {
        switch (key.keyCode) {
            case 13:
                startGame();
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

The only things left out are the two variables `map` and `map_Default` which are arrays of strings.

Here it is published: http://camron.onyxtek.com/Main/AsciiGame/

Comment: So basically what the code is telling us is that firstly you have multiple elements with the same ID, and secondly you're using a method that overwrites all the content, html(), and you're wondering why it overwrites all the content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one element with a given id.

So

```
$("#GameContainer")
```

contains only one element and thus

```
$("#GameContainer").eq(i)
```

makes no sense.

But it seems that what you want is the child of index `i` **in** `#GameContainer`. You can get it with

```
$("#GameContainer .tilerow").eq(i)
```

Comment: I don't understand? Are you saying elements with an id can only contain one element?

Comment: It's illegal to give the same id to two elements in HTML.

Comment: Oh, I don't think I tried to do that edit: nope, didn't.

Comment: `$("#GameContainer").eq(i)` takes the element of index `i` among the ones having id `GameContainer`. But maybe what you want is `$("#GameContainer .tilerow").eq(i)` ?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. That actually fixed it. One last thing though, why would $("#GameContainer") contain only one element when it has multiple children?

Comment: Because the set doesn't contain the children, just the elements matching the selector.